# Vuejs - Attach blob as an email attachment and download .eml file

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, blob, eml

I am getting a blob from server, which can contain a pdf or tiff file. I have a button called email. On click, i want to get that blob, create an .eml file, attach that blob file as an attachment and then download that .eml file. Upon opening downloaded file, i want local email client ( mainly outlook) to open with attached file.

My attempt

```
downloadEMLFile(blob, blob.type, fileName);

function downloadEMLFile(blobFile, blobType, fileName) {
  // Metadata for EML file
  const sender = "sender@example.com";
  const recipient = "recipient@example.com";
  const subject = "Your Subject";
  const body = "Your email body";

  // Create a new EML file content
  const emlContent = `
    From: ${sender}
    To: ${recipient}
    Subject: ${subject}
    X-Unsent: 1
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="boundary"

    --boundary
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

    ${body}

    --boundary
    Content-Type: ${blobType}; name="${fileName}"
    Content-Disposition: attachment
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

    ${blobFile}
    --boundary--
  `;

  const emlBlob = new Blob([emlContent], { type: "message/rfc822" });

  // Create a download link and trigger the download
  const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(emlBlob);
  downloadLink.download = `${subject}.eml`;
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

My outlook response
[image]

Comment: which part of that are you having an issue with?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**